# Unable to set items with Selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am not able to add items to a selectize.js input either at initialisation or dynamically. Unfortunately I've had to guess how some of this is meant to work; the official examples don't cover adding items dynamically and other examples I have found on sites like jsfiddle simply don't work.

I am passing in an array of items `items: ids` to populate the input with some default values. This does not seem to function at all.

As a workaround for this I tried to add items dynamically with a for loop, however I get back `Uncaught ReferenceError: $selectize is not defined`.

How do I correctly add items at initialisation and also add them after in a for loop?

```js
let ids = [
  274656,
  290547,
  384956,
  17864,
  12804,
  127485
];

let selectize = $('#id-input').selectize({
  delimiter: ',',
  persist: false,
  items: ids,
  plugins: [
    'restore_on_backspace',
    'remove_button'
  ],
  create: function(input) {
    return {
      value: input,
      text: input
    }
  }
});

let select = $selectize[0].selectize;
for (let asset of assets) {
  selector.addItem('test');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id-input" type="text">
```

Comment: `let $selectize` instead of `let selectize`? (for your `$selectize is not defined` error)

Comment: Please add selectize.js